# Azure Devops Board vs Jira

Tags: azure-devops, jira

I am comparing Jira against Azure Devops Board and notices few limitation:

**1. Components field**

JIRA - Components are sub-sections of a project; they are used to group issues within a project into smaller parts. Components add some structures to the projects, breaking it up into features, teams, modules, subprojects and more. Using components you can generate reports, collect statistics, and display it on dashboards and so on.

To add new components, as shown in the above screen you can add name, description, component lead and default assignee.

DEVOPS BOARD - No component field, even if we can customized to add one, it is just a String.

**2. No Issue-Type Prefix Ticket ID**

JIRA - We can customized to have an issue key, -. For example : REQ-1313

DEVOPS BOARD -  Just a number.

**3. Workflow Sequencing**

JIRA - We can use workflow properties for changing the order of the sequence of transition buttons. So from "Ready" state, we can either go back to "New" / "In Progress" / "Rejected" but not "In Testing"

DEVOPS BOARD - Seems like we can jump to any state we want.

---

I'm not sure if I'm misconfigure, but if so, please provide a way to do so, or maybe an alternatives to limitations listed above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Component field**

Azure DevOps uses the Area Path field for that purpose. [About area and iteration paths (aka sprints)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-areas-iterations?view=azure-devops), [Define area paths and assign to a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

**2. No Issue-Type Prefix Ticket ID**

I can not understand where is a problem here? Can you describe some example?

**3. Workflow Sequencing**

You can restrict change of the State field with rules: [Prevent reopening work item once closed](https://adityabajaj.com/prevent-reopening-work-item-azure-devops/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will look into that!
As for no 2, in Jira we can specify prefix to differentiate type of subproject, with format 
<PROJECTCODE>-<TICKETNO>, i.e;
 PROA-1 , PROB-1, PROC-1. 

So we can identify the subproject based on the prefix.